# serviceContainer returns an IdentityTranslator in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, symfony-components

I'm trying to use the `translation` component but I'm not able to get it - and use - properly.

When I request /testT:

```
namespace Codechick\Test2Bundle\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/testT")
     */
    public function testTAction(Request $req)
    {
        die(var_dump($this->get('translator')));
    }
}
```

What I get is this:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Translation\IdentityTranslator)[203]
  private 'selector' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector)[202]
  private 'locale' => string 'it' (length=2)
```

hence, **nothing** is being translated. Why is that? Here is my configuration (there are no overrides in my _dev conf):

```
#<root>/app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: [it,en] }
```

Comment: Is it supposed to translate `it` to `en`? What's the problem?

Comment: It was supposed to translate from the key to it. Otherwise to en if it is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In according with the [news announcement](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-improvements-for-the-translation-component), from the version 2.6 the translator component is defined as service like `translator.default`.

So change your code:

```
    die(var_dump($this->get('translator')));
```

with

```
    die(var_dump($this->get('translator.default')));
```

Hope this help

Comment: That definitely solved the problem of getting an instance of Translator, but when I try to output the translated key nothing seems to be translated. I tried to look for something in the log (like a warning, according to the documentation) but nothing about the translator seems to be logged. Any suggestions?

Comment: Plus, I think the documentation still refers to `translator` in place of `translator.default`. http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/translation.html#basic-translation do you think it's valid anyway?

Comment: Hi @Bertuz you can check that you have correctly configured the messages with the command `translation:update` executing it as example, `app/console translation:update it --dump-messages`

Comment: it actually seems to be well configured. The key appears with a cozy `[OK] 1 messages were successfully extracted.` But by using `$this->get('translator.default')->trans('<key>');` the key is not translated

Comment: @Bertuz try setting only one fallback in the configuration like this:     `translator:      { fallback: it }`

Comment: you can also check for the configuration with the command `app/console debug:container --parameters  | grep locale`

Comment: nope, nothing changes! I tried to figure out what's happening by calling
`die(dump($translator->getMessages()));` and `die(dump($translator->getLocale()));`. Locale says 'it' which is what I expect, but `getMessages`returns a disappointing empty array. Sigh.

Comment: nope, nothing happens with `app/console cache:clear
`. Daje, I move this issue into another question. This was actually regarding getting the correct Translation instance. Thank you

Comment: here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338186/translatorgetmessages-returns-an-empty-array