# Translator::getMessages returns an empty array

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to use the `translator.default` service in a `Controller`, but any message I'm trying to translate by means of the `trans` method returns the untranslated key.

```
/**
 * @Route("/testT")
 */
public function testTAction(Request $req)
{
    $translator = $this->get('translator.default');
    $translated = $translator->trans('Hello from the other side');
    die(dump($translated));
}
```

In order to be sure my keys were correctly loaded I've done the following checks:

```
php app/console translation:update it --dump-messages
```

which outputs the following:

```
Translation Messages Extractor and Dumper
=========================================

 // Generating "it" translation files for "app folder"
 // Parsing templates...
 // Loading translation files...

Messages extracted for domain "messages" (1 messages)
-----------------------------------------------------

 * Hello from the other side


 [OK] 1 messages were successfully extracted
```

my keys are stored under `<root>/app/resources/translations/messages.it.yml`
and my locale, when requesting the translated key is well set up:

```
    $translator = $this->get('translator.default');
    die(dump($translator->getLocale()));
```

if called in my controller, this generates the following output: **"it"**, which I guess it's correct. So: where am I wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my `<root>/app/Resources/translations/messages.it.yml`

```
Hello from the other side: Ciao dall'altra parte
```

and Here is the chunk related to the translation service in my `<root>/app/config/config.yml`

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: it }
```

I'm using the dev configuration, but nothing is related to the translation there.

Comment: is the translator configured in your config.yml?can you post your messages.it.yml?

Comment: I've just edited my post with the info you requested

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the cache after creating the new `messages.it.yml` file?

It has already happened to me that the translation appears as 'not found', even when I'm sure it's there. After clearing the cache it normally works.

Also for the future, you can run under app_dev and check the profiler to see the messages that are found and the missing messages, like this:

[image: Profiler toolbar with translations]

When you click at the translation icon, you should see a screen with a list like this:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I've called `php app/console cache:clear` but nothing changes. Interestingly my app_dev.php doesn't show anything about the messages. Plus, nothing about the translation service is in the log files!

Comment: should I maybe add a loader by myself?

Comment: Just a question, your file is `<root>/app/Resource/translations/messages.it.yml`here?
or is it just a typo? It should be `Resources` (in plural)

Comment: yes, silly me, it's a typo! It's just in "Resources"

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, have you checked [Debugging Symfony Translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#debugging-translations)?

As seen there, you can run `php app/console debug:translation it` and see the table of translated messages for the `it` locale.

Comment: I've tried to use `{{ 'Hello from the other side'|trans }}` inside a twig template. After that, if I run `php app/console debug:translation it` 'state' is empty, the domain is "messages" and the Id is "Hello from the other side". The message preview (it) is correct: "Ciao dall'altra parte". But when the twig is rendered what I get is still the id! Of course if I remove it from the twig the status returns "unused". I've also checked the locale with a request object and is set to "it".

Comment: When you do the translation inside a twig template, are you using the symfony profiler toolbar? If it isn't translating it should display a "missing" message like in the first image I sent.

Comment: I've tried to start a project from scratch just to make sure that something wasn't well set up. I got to say that on the new project everything works well! I really don't know what's going on, maybe I've touched something wrong as it was my very first project in symfony

Comment: Well, that's weird. But at least it's working now! :)